# How to save a custom class to permanent storage on Android?

Tags: android, parcelable

Hi: I've got a custom class and I want to save it to an Assests file. The reason I want to do this is to be able to restore the state of my program with ease at the touch of a button. Basically I have a bunch of String lists and simple strings and numbers collected in a class and I want to write a function that will write all of that in the Assets file. I wanted to implement this by having the class implement Parcelable and using its methods for writing in the open file, the raw data. However while reading the documentation I came across this line:

```
This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport. As such, it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent storage: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data in the Parcel can render older data unreadable.
```

Which kind of got me wandering if there is a better way? I don't want to write the file as text as I feel that would be terribly inefficient. Any other ideas? Thank you very much in advance....

Comment: "I've got a custom class and I want to save it to an Assests file" -- that is not possible, as assets are read-only at runtime.

Comment: As I wrote that line I figured out that I never thought if an Asset file could be written. Thank you. I doesn't matter though I can get do by with internal storage files..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to understand, persisting Parcelable data is a bad idea.

You probably don't really want to persist your data in text files on external storage in most cases.

You'd probably be best served to use a database.  [Here is a link to a SQLite tutorial that should get you started.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I will look into it. But I was thinking of using somthing a bit more primitive, like this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal Only thing I'm not sure of is how to read the data back.. seems like you have to calculate the number of bytes for every write....

Comment: Okay, then do it that way.  You have all the information you need to do it either way.

Comment: Thanks, but am I right? Do you need to calculate the number of bytes in order to get the information back?

Comment: You'll have to design your own scheme to separate the values you write to the file and you'll have to know which value goes where.

Comment: Why would you bother with all that when you can get the SQLite database to take care of that burden for you and you could just query the db and recreate the object you need?  Also, as CommonsWare points out your understanding of the terminology could use a little work.  Assets files must be included at compile time and are read-only at runtime.

Comment: My knowledge of databases is very small. Very small. So any trouble that might arise from an implementation (which from your tutorial seems long) would be very hard for me to debug, which equals longer development time. I've allready had succes in the way which I've proposed for simple tests. Let me ask you somthing: Can I write more complex estructures to the DB such as ArrayList<String> directly? Or Would I need to read them one by one. As for the Assests question, I answered I recongnized my mistake, allready. Still it does seem like the more appropiate solution. I'll see if I try it.

Comment: I solved my problem siply by using DataInput and OutputStream as it has convenience functions for writing different basic types. Thanks for all of the answers.